# How many tags is ideal for a question?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I set 3 tags on a question I feel like I didn't give my question the right paradigm to be answered completely within the question scope. However setting 4 tags feels like an overkill and I' afraid will drive people's focus away from answering the question. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You might be treating tags a bit too mechanically. There is no ideal {X} number of tags anymore so than one might say there's an ideal number of words for a title.

Tags are an ad hoc categorization system to **highlight the "key concepts"** present in your question. If one tag adequately describes the scope of your question, so be it. If you need more than five tags, you're likely adding too much detail.

Start with the [tags tab](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/tags) to see how this site chooses to categorize their questions. Then scan the body of your question to identify the top concepts that describe your question. Sometimes it helps to pretend you're at the help desk's *main reception,* and you're trying to get redirected to the department and personnel who can help you without getting into a lot unnecessary detail.

> *"How can I help you?"*
>
> *"I have a questions about Tridion 2011 [2011]… It's about the Content Manager Explorer [CME]… I'm having trouble extending the user interface [gui-extensions]."*

Also note that tags should *not* be used to add context to your question — all the necessary information should be contained in the *body* of your question — so tagging should have little effect on changing the question's focus or getting it answered.